# List of Facebook liked pages

Tags: facebook, like

I have a site with a lot of pages that have a Facebook like button.

Is there a way to get all the pages that were liked with the number of likes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931104/how-to-get-number-of-likes-from-facebook-like-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked a few times on Stack Overflow and is best suited on their since it requires coding via Facebooks API, Thanks to Rink for pointing out the below information.

> SOURCE: 
>   [How to get number of likes from Facebook Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931104/how-to-get-number-of-likes-from-facebook-like-button)
>
> There are two ways to get the number of facebook likes.
>
> ```
> Graph API
> ```
>
> `http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http%3a%2f%2ffacebook.com`
>
> Result is JSON: (For some reason 'likes' are called 'shares')
>
> ```
> {
>    "http://facebook.com": {
>       "id": "http://facebook.com",
>       "shares": 35641554,
>       "comments": 339
>    }
> }
> ```
>
> 1. FQL
>
>    `http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select+total_count+from+link_stat+where+url="http://facebook.com"`
>
> Result:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <fql_query_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" list="true">
>   <link_stat>
>     <total_count>35641554</total_count>
>   </link_stat>
> </fql_query_response>
> ```